# Can I check if an element exists within a nested list at a specific index?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Someone recently posted this question. Before I could respond with my answer, the post was removed. The request was to check for the existence of an integer value within a 4x4 array without defining a function.
Given a value and a column the answer would be:

`if sum([True for x in array2d if x[col] == value]) > 0:`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import random


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # initialize a 4 x 4 array with integers
    array2d = [[x for x in range(0,4)] for i in range(0,4)]

    # shuffle the numbers for variability
    for i in range(1,4):
        random.shuffle(array2d[i])

    # print each row for validation
    for row in array2d:
        print(row)

    # pick colum 2 to check for value 2
    col = 2
    value = 2

    if sum([True for x in array2d if x[col] == value]) > 0:
        print("value {0} found in colum {0}".format(value, col))
    else:
        print("value {0} missing in colum {0}".format(value, col))

    # pick colum 3 to check for value 2
    col = 2
    value = 20 # This vauel will always be missing.

    if any([True for x in array2d if x[col] == value]) > 0:
        print("value {0} found in colum {0}".format(value, col))
    else:
        print("value {0} missing in colum {0}".format(value, col))
```

Comment: you can create a same 4*4 list more elegantly, `[list(range(0,4))]*4`

Comment: Thank you. I'll keep that in mind. The meat of the response was for the if statement without needing to define a function. But once again, I will keep that in mind. Thanks again

Comment: I'm not even sure I should have posted this. I wasn't sure why the original author removed the question. I figured if he still needed an answer, I would post a new question with his original text.

Comment: Wait: so are you answering a question in a question? If so, when creating the question there should be a little "answer my own question" checkbox.

Comment: Instead of using the implicit conversion of True to 1 with the `sum` method, you should use `any`

Comment: Thank you @BlueSheepToken, I have updated the question to reflect your suggestion +1

Comment: @SufiyanGhori, [list(range(0,4))]*4 will produce a list of lists; however, each row will have the same list. Try your suggestion and use id() to see each row's identity value. Then use list comprehension and you will see each row has its own id.

Comment: @Tomothy32, I was not aware of the "answer my own question" checkbox. I tried to edit this question, and I didn't see it on the edit form. I will keep that in mind for the future. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

your going to want to traverse the 2 dimensional array with nested for loops.

first initialize a boolean isFound to false. and ints i and j to -1. use iterators i and j to represent the current row and current column being search. check if the waldo that u are searching for is in the given array's column i row j. if so u have found waldo, so record the location by storing a tuple with i and j, and change your isFound boolean to true. if not increment the iterators and keep traversing the array.

```
waldo = #value being searched
array[][] = #array being traversed
isFound = False
i = -1
j = -1


for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
        if array[i][j] == waldo:
            isFound = True
            location = (i, j)

print('found waldo? ', isFound)
print('location: array[', i, '][', j, ']')
```

output (examples):

```
found waldo? true    
location: array[3][2]

found waldo? false    
location: array[-1][-1]
```

Comment: Add some explanation in your answer, explaining your code and how it solves the problem.

Comment: Hi @paolo-secci. There are some syntax errors in your answer. Please make sure the code runs before suggesting it as an answer. e.g. Python uses `True` and `False` rather than `true` and `false`. Also, `i, j = -1` is invalid.